# Node express HTML to PDF

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pdf

I'm looking to render a pdf version of a webpage directly to the browser using express. Something like express.render() only render the page as pdf

I have found a module that will convert HTML or a URL to a pdf

https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf

What i need to know is how can I use the response from that libary directly in a HTTP route handler to respond to requests with the PDF, I would prefer not to store the PDF, I just want to render it on the fly, and return it as a buffer or a stream to the browser

This is the basic API the module provides:

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
pdf.create(html).toFile([filepath, ]function(err, res){
  console.log(res.filename);
});

pdf.create(html).toStream(function(err, stream){
  stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./foo.pdf'));
});

pdf.create(html).toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
  console.log('This is a buffer:', Buffer.isBuffer(buffer));
});
```

I want to use one of these methods stream or buffer and wrap it in a route handler like this one:

```
router.get('invoice/pdf', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).send(..pdf data);
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is quite easy to do in Node just using streams. The primary reason to use a stream over a `Buffer` is that a stream doesn't need to keep all of its data in memory like a `Buffer` does. Instead it can provide the data as needed to the reader or writer. This means that it is lightweight and will be better for performance in regards to latency and throughput.

In your case, you just want to `pipe()` the contents of the stream directly to your `res` object.

```
router.get('/invoice/pdf', (req, res) => {
  pdf.create(html).toStream((err, pdfStream) => {
    if (err) {   
      // handle error and return a error response code
      console.log(err)
      return res.sendStatus(500)
    } else {
      // send a status code of 200 OK
      res.statusCode = 200             

      // once we are done reading end the response
      pdfStream.on('end', () => {
        // done reading
        return res.end()
      })

      // pipe the contents of the PDF directly to the response
      pdfStream.pipe(res)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: That is exactly why I asked I wanted to know the best way to do it and that is exactly what you have specified. Thanks!

Comment: Do I need to specify that the response is a pdf res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');

Comment: Express should auto detect the file extension so no but , you can explicitly set it anyway if you'd like. If Express detects that you've already given a `Content-Type` header to the response object's `headers` via `res.setHeader()` then it will skip over assigning that header a value.

Comment: Slight typo in your code you might want to correct pdfStream is refered to as stream on both stream.on and stream.pipe ;-)

Comment: @MartinWebb thanks, sometimes writing code directly in the answer box leads to some mistakes >.<

Comment: Otherwise, your implementations is simple and awesome, works a charm - I'm it will come in useful to a lot of folks.